# findAndCountAll function takes too much times causing AWS lambda to timeout, is there any way to limit the count

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize to fetch data from database, we have implemented pagination so we set the limit 50 in findandcountall function. The lambda works the way we want but if the count is more than 1 million the lambda timeout. We need the total count to implement pagination. Is there any way we put a limit of count so the lambda doesn't timeout?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate

Comment: Does the user really need to know how many pages there are going to be, given that there are over 1m items? What would the pagination UI be in that scenario?

Comment: @jarmod For a good user experience the number of pages is needed so that users can navigate to other pages directly, we basically disable the page numbers on the basis of the count. It isn't compulsory we get 1m items we can get 1000 or even less data

Comment: Sure, if you have relatively few items then it's worth being accurate but beyond a certain number it's often unnecessary. You can use the estimated count to decide if you need to get an accurate count e.g. if estimated is less than 1000, which would be 20 pages of 50 items and is probably more than you would need for any pagination UI. See how Google search results do pagination, for example - they have a sliding window of 10 pages that you choose from or you can click prev/next buttons. They don't need an accurate count of how many pages there are.